# Publish updates to facebook app page using PHP sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I post updates to my facebook page through my website?

I have created the facebook app for my website using php sdk and want to include a functionality wherein whenever there I post an update to my website it should get automatically published to my facebook app page.

I have tried several tutorials and none seem to work for some reason or another. Here is a sample of my code:

```
$page_id = '*****';

$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");

if( !empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
    $args = array('access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'], 
                  'message' => "This is the message to be posted on wall");

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's your error but the if statement isn't closed. You're missing a closing `}` somewhere.

Comment: This is just a part of the code. Rest assured there are no errors with the syntax!

Comment: which means that the `$post_id` is within the if?